# How to add class to list depends on text?

Tags: jquery

In some page, my side menu is created dynamically like this.

```
<div id="tree" class="treeview">
<ul><li><a href="Salg.asp" title="" class="">Salg</a></li>
<li><a href="Retur.asp" title="" class="">Retur</a></li>
<li><a href="Support.asp" title="" class="active">Support</a> </li>
<li><a href="konomi.asp" title="" class="">Økonomi</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!-- end of tree treeview -->
```

In other page all the list have different text such as product categories etc.

Now I need to add padding to li in the menu where list texts are Salg, Retur, Support, and Økonomi.

This means I need to add a class "listpad" to li where the texts are Salg, Retur, Support, and Økonomi.

Could anyone tell me how to do this please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) filter selector for that like this:

```
$('ul#tree li:contains("Salg")').addClass('listpad');
$('ul#tree li:contains("Retur")').addClass('listpad');
$('ul#tree li:contains("Support")').addClass('listpad');
$('ul#tree li:contains("Økonomi")').addClass('listpad');
```